# rigid body moves by addForce but the object itself doesn't

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THnivyG0Mvo and This is my shoot function

```c#
void Shoot()
{
    muzzleFlash.Play();
    shootingSound.Play();
    RaycastHit hit;
    if( Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
    {
        //Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

        Enemy1 target = hit.transform.GetComponent<Enemy1>();
        if (target != null)
        {
            target.TakeDamage(damage);
        }

        if(hit.rigidbody != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("******************");
            hit.rigidbody.AddForce( - hit.normal * impactForce);
        }


        GameObject impactGo = Instantiate(impactEffect, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
        Destroy(impactGo, 0.3f);
    }
}
```

Rigidbody added to target:

[image]

Barrel component:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6xrY.png)

This function is in my Rifle.cs script which is being added to a rifle object. Everything works fine. But, when I hit an object which has a Rigidbody, it doesn't move but I can see in the scene that the Rigidbody is moving when I hit it many times. The Rigidbody of the target is set to 'Use Gravity' and 'Is Kinematic' is not checked. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the heirarchy of your object that contains the `Rigidbody` and has the `Enemy1` script?  It's important to see where the collider is, where the rigidbody is, and where the renderer representing its visuals is.

Comment: Maybe you are hitting with so little force, try making impactForce higher

Comment: @Foggzie Enemy1 is not necessary. Right ? Because the first nested if statement is used to reduce the health of enemy but adding force is being done in the second nested if statement. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I will add the screen shot of a barrel that I'm trying to move with force

Comment: @Horothenic Thanks for your comment. But, this is not the problem as the Rigidbody is moving when I hit the object but the object rendered is not moving (the visual object) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I have done a lot of google search. This answered my question https://forum.unity.com/threads/mesh-renderer-does-not-move-with-parent-rigid-body.204700/. So What I needed to do it to turn off (unchecked) static in the top right of the inspector for the object.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIaT6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the force you are adding is too small, so it needs a lot of shots to make some effect, as @Horothenic says, try to increase the value of the impactForce Variable. Look if the rigidbody, the mesh renderer, and the colliders are attached to the same object in the scene. The title of your question suggests your rigidbody is moving but your render doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Give the force a ForceMode. Since you want the object to look shot, I would recommend using impulse and make sure the force is bigger than the objects mass by a big factor.

```
    if(hit.rigidbody != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("******************");
        hit.rigidbody.AddForce((-hit.normal * impactForce), ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
```

See this page for more info. [Force Modes in Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting ForceMode.Impulse. It added cool effect of shooting :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the Animator completely, the animations have an option to write defaults, if the movement was edited on animation it misbehaves because it wants to set the default.